# Easier ways to make an RPG dice roller code?

Tags: python, beginner

I'm new to programming and this is the first thing I'm doing on my own. I would appreciate it if you could point me ways to optimize this RPG dice roller code in Python!

```
import random

def dice_reader():

##this should read messages like '2 d 6 + 3, 5 d 20 + 2 or just 3 d 8'##
    message = input('>')
    reader = message.split(' ')
    times = reader[0]
    sides = reader[2]
    output_with_modifier = []
    result = []

    if len(reader) == 5:
        modifier = reader[4]
    else:
        modifier = 0

    for output in range(int(times)):
        output = random.randint(1, int(sides))
        result.append(output)
        output_with_modifier = [(int(x) + int(modifier)) for x in result]
    print(f' Dice rolls: {tuple(result)}')
    if modifier != 0:
        print(f' With modifier: {tuple(output_with_modifier)}')


    end = False
    while end == False:
        dice_reader()
        end_message = input('Again? ')
        if end_message.lower() == 'no':
            end = True
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the performance tag, because nothing here will challenge your CPU or memory (even remotely).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Mystery inputs

It's clear that there's an implied structure to this input:

```
message = input('>')
reader = message.split(' ')
```

requiring between four and five tokens. I have no idea what those are, and neither does your user. Replace `'>'` with an actual description of what's expected here.

### Unpacking

```
times = reader[0]
sides = reader[2]
```

can be

```
times, _, sides = reader[:3]
```

though the discarded second item is suspicious. You do need to show what this is, and it probably shouldn't be there.

### Looping and overwrites

This:

```
for output in range(int(times)):
    output_with_modifier = [(int(x) + int(modifier)) for x in result]
```

does not make sense. If you ask for 100 times, `output_with_modifier` will be calculated 100 times and thrown away 99 of them. Only the last value will be kept. You probably want to de-indent that last assignment so that it happens outside of the loop.

### More looping

```
end = False
while end == False:
    dice_reader()
    end_message = input('Again? ')
    if end_message.lower() == 'no':
        end = True
else:
    pass
```

First, delete that `else; pass` - it isn't doing anything. Also, `end == False` should be `not end`; but you shouldn't be using a termination variable at all. If you find a `no`, simply `break`.

### Suggested code

Some of this may challenge a beginner, but I like to think that CodeReview is for "aspiring advanced programmers". I've tried to comment it extensively, but feel free to ask questions in the comments.

```
import re
from random import randint
from re import Pattern
from typing import ClassVar, Iterable


class Dice:
    """
    One specification for dice rolls in Dungeons & Dragons-like format.
    """

    def __init__(self, times: int, sides: int, modifier: int = 0):
        if times < 1:
            raise ValueError(f'times={times} is not a positive integer')
        if sides < 1:
            raise ValueError(f'sides={sides} is not a positive integer')

        self.times, self.sides, self.modifier = times, sides, modifier

    # This is a class variable (basically a "static") that only has one copy
    # for the entire class type, rather than a copy for every class instance
    # It is a regular expression pattern that will allow us to parse user
    # input.
    INPUT_PAT: ClassVar[Pattern] = re.compile(
        # From the start, maybe some whitespace, then a group named "times"
        # that contains one or more digits
        r'^\s*(?P<times>\d+)'    
        
        # Maybe some whitespace, then the letter "d"
        r'\s*d'
        
        # Maybe some whitespace, then a group named "sides" that contains one
        # or more digits
        r'\s*(?P<sides>\d+)'
        
        # The beginning of a group that we do not store.
        r'(?:'
        
            # Maybe some whitespace, then a "+" character
            r'\s*\+'
        
            # Maybe some whitespace, then a group named "modifier" that
            # contains one or more digits
            r'\s*(?P<modifier>\d+)'
        
        # End of the group that we do not store; mark it optional
        r')?'
        
        # Maybe some whitespace, then the end.
        r'\s*$',

        # We might use "d" or "D"
        re.IGNORECASE
    )

    # This can only be called on the class type, not a class instance. It
    # returns a new class instance, so it acts as a secondary constructor.
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, message: str) -> 'Rolls':
        match = cls.INPUT_PAT.match(message)
        if match is None:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid dice specification string "{message}"')

        # Make a new instance of this class based on the matched regular
        # expression.
        return cls(
            int(match['times']),
            int(match['sides']),
            # If there was no modifier specified, pass 0.
            0 if match['modifier'] is None else int(match['modifier']),
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_stdin(cls) -> 'Rolls':
        """
        Parse and return a new Rolls instance from stdin.
        """

        while True:
            try:
                message = input(
                    'Enter your dice specification, of the form\n'
                    '<times>d<sides> [+ modifier], e.g. 3d6 or 4d12 + 1:\n'
                )
                return cls.parse(message)
            except ValueError as v:
                print(v)
                print('Please try again.')

    def roll(self, with_modifier: bool = False) -> Iterable[int]:
        """
        Return a generator of rolls. This is "lazy" and will only execute the
        rolls that are consumed by the caller, because it returns a generator
        (not a list or a tuple).
        """
        mod = self.modifier if with_modifier else 0
        return (
            randint(1, self.sides) + mod
            for _ in range(self.times)
        )

    def print_roll(self):
        print(
            'Dice rolls:',
            ', '.join(str(x) for x in self.roll()),
        )

        if self.modifier != 0:
            print(
                'With modifier:',
                ', '.join(str(x) for x in self.roll(with_modifier=True)),
            )


def test():
    """
    This is an automated test method that does some sanity checks on the Dice
    implementation.
    """
    
    d = Dice.parse('3 d 6')
    assert d.times == 3
    assert d.sides == 6
    assert d.modifier == 0

    d = Dice.parse('3D6 + 2')
    assert d.times == 3
    assert d.sides == 6
    assert d.modifier == 2

    try:
        Dice.parse('nonsense')
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError as v:
        assert str(v) == 'Invalid dice specification string "nonsense"'

    try:
        Dice.parse('-2d5')
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError as v:
        assert str(v) == 'Invalid dice specification string "-2d5"'

    try:
        Dice.parse('0d6')
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError as v:
        assert str(v) == "times=0 is not a positive integer"

    d = Dice.parse('100 d 12+3')
    n = 0
    for x in d.roll(True):
        assert 4 <= x <= 15
        n += 1
    assert n == 100


def main():
    test()

    dice = Dice.from_stdin()
    dice.print_roll()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I should've used comments to clarify what this is all about, my bad lol. This code is for reading messages like "2 d 10 + 3", for RPG dice rolling. Although "d" is completely useless, it makes for the classic virtual dice roller structure. It should print a message with the structure need for reading. Besides that, I didn't about anything you pointed me out, thanks for the help, I didn't expect any answers.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you very much for your time and suggestions. I will definitely study that, as didn't expect such an answer. I would also like to extend it a bit and ask another question: I'm a little overwhelmed by the amount of stuff that comes along with Python (Atom, Pycharm, Anaconda, virtual environments) and I don't know where to start. What do I really need to play around with Python a little, but without limiting myself?

Comment: Personally my favourite environment is PyCharm. It goes a long way to suggesting where things are wrong or non-standard.